Try to verify a deployed Contract without the setting of optimizer
I deployed a contract one year ago, it works well and now I want to verify it to public code to the client, but the problem is: I can't remember what I set in the optimizer setting before. I tried several common settings which I usually use, but all of them not work:

enable: true, runs: 200
enable: true, runs: 200, yul: true
enable: true, runs: 500
enable: true, runs: 500, yul: true
enable: true, runs: 200, yul: true, yulDetails: {stackAllocation: true, optimizerSteps: "dhfoDgvulfnTUtnIf"}
...

I can ensure the source code does not change, because I have only one version.
How can I verify it?

The difficulty with verification is that it either works or it doesn't - there's nothing in-between. And you get no feedback about what went wrong.
So the problem may be in your optimizer settings. But it may also be elsewhere - maybe the code accidentally changed? Or maybe you updated some dependencies? Maybe different Solidity version?
The 200 runs for optimizer is the default in most tools, I believe.
Unfortunately, I don't have a clear answer to give. You just have to try different options what could've changed.

Thank you, may I must try more
